# How to convert a MaskedTextBox value to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

So far I've tried this:

```
try
{
    TimeSpan durtime = TimeSpan.Parse(timeDur.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad Format", timeDur.ToString());
}
```

`timeDur` is a MaskedTextBox with a mask of type `__:__` (Validating type DateTime).

When I try to convert the `timedur` MaskedTextBox into a string format, it gives me an exception of type System.FormatException:

> "The string was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan."

Comment: Shouldn't it be `timeDur.Text`?

Comment: `TimeSpan` is the difference between two `DateTime`s. It is not a `DateTime`

Comment: What's the value of "timeDur.ToString()"?

Comment: @Starceaker the value is HH:mm. It is a user input value.

Comment: If timeDur.ToString() returns "HH:mm", then that's not a valid `TimeSpan`; that's the custom format string that formats a time as hours and minutes in 24 hour time format (00 - 23).  You want to get `timeDur.Text` and parse it.  Incidentally, you could use the `TryParse` method to get convert the `try-catch` block into an `if` statement.

Comment: What is the value of `timeDur.ToString()` _exactly_ when you debug your code?

Comment: It is a user input and can be anything in this format: 00:00
When I output it in a MessageBox for example, it says: 21:30, 06:30....(depending on the user output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly have no idea why it started working now but

```
etimeWHP1.Value = btimeWHP1.Value.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(timeDur.Text));
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a DateTimePicker with Format "Time"?

This way you don't have to worry about Culture specific formatting and so on.

Comment: I need a TimeSpan type, because I need to do arithmetic operations with this value afterwards.

Comment: You can use the value of the DateTimePicker the same way you can use the value of the FormattedTextBox. Only with with Time option of the DateTimePicker you don't have to worry about the user entering something like 30:86 for example. That's what I meant.